# Deciding whether an integer polynomial has an integer root

Tags: decision-problem, polynomials

This is a question written by my instructor Z. Loria .

> Consider the following problem: Given a polynomial $p(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^i$, where $a_i$ are integers, is there a natural number $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $p(n) = 0$?
>
> Show that this problem is decidable by presenting an algorithm in pseudocode that always either outputs such an $n$, or stops in finite time and declares that no such $n$ exists.

I've to present the above algorithm.

The naïve approach will be to iterate through all the possibilities, but the problem is that it never terminates when the polynomial has no integer roots.

I was thinking about finding some upper bound on the value of $x$ and only then iterate through all the possibilities (accept if found, decline if not).

I vaguely remember that for polynomials in that form we can find some $x$ such that $|p(x)|$ only grows, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: Hint, $p(x)$ is basically $a_nx^n$ when $|x|$ is large enough.

Comment: You are in the right track. Try to (algebraically) find a value for $x$ large enough so that $|P(x)|$ only increases after it

Comment: Maybe start with doing a few examples and plotting them out (on Desmos for example)

Comment: We require you to credit the original source of all copied/quoted material: https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing.  I have given you this feedback before: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/140887/breaking-rsa-when-sent-message-belongs-to-a-small-set#comment295836_140887

Comment: @D.W. That's copied from my university assignment, how does I credit that?

Comment: Credit the author -- which means the instructor of that course.  If there is a publicly available copy of the assignment, link to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Let's call the root $\xi$, because $n$ here means the degree of the polynomial. That's seriously bugging me about the question.)

The secret is in noticing that it's easy to test if $\xi$ is a root, since you just evaluate the polynomial, but you only need to test a finite number of candidates.

As a first observation, if $\xi$ is an integer root of the polynomial, then $\left| \xi \right| \le \left| a_0 \right|$, so you only need to test $2\left| a_0 \right|+1$ candidates. In fact, you can do better than this because $\left| \xi \right|$ must be a factor of $\left| a_0 \right|$ by the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem). So you need only test the factors (both positive and negative) of $a_0$. Either way, a finite number of candidates.

As a second observation, if

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n} a_i\,\xi^i = 0$$

Then for any positive integer $m$

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n} a_i\,\xi^i \cong 0\mod m$$

So, for example, if

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n} a_i\,2^i \not\cong 0\mod 3$$

then there cannot be a root of the polynomial $\xi$ such that $\xi \cong 2 \mod 3$.

Conversely, suppose that for two different coprime moduli $m_1$ and $m_2$, you find
all integers $0 \le \xi_j < m_1$ and $0 \le \upsilon_k < m_2$ such that

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n} a_i\,\xi_j^i \cong 0\mod m_1$$

and

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n} a_i\,\upsilon_k^i \cong 0\mod m_2$$

then you can use the [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) to find all $0 \le \psi_l < m_1 m_2$ such that

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n} a_i\,\psi_l^i \cong 0\mod m_1 m_2$$

This is an important optimisation in practice (i.e. in real computer algebra systems) because evaluating the polynomial might require large integer arithmetic since intermediate values may be larger than a machine word. Using this technique, you can use word-sized integer operations to eliminate a lot of candidates.

Answer (score 2):

$$|ax^3+bx^2+cx+d|>0$$ is equivalent to

$$\left|1+\frac bax^{-1}+\frac cax^{-2}+\frac dax^{-3}\right|>0.$$

Clearly, the limit of the LHS is $1$, and by continuity, there will be a *finite* $X$ such that $x>X$ implies the above inequality. This generalizes to any degree.

---

You can take

$$X>\max\left(\left|\frac{3b}a\right|,\sqrt{\left|\frac{3c}a\right|},\sqrt[3]{\left|\frac{3d}a\right|}\right).$$

Answer (score 1):

If $a_n = 1$, then all integer roots are divisors of $a_0$, either positive or negative, and all other roots are irrational or complex. The integer roots can often be found quite quickly.

It's only slightly more difficult if $a_n ≠ ± 1$: Multiply each coefficient by $a_n^{n-1}$, then let $y = x \cdot a_n$ or $x = y / a_n$. You get an equation for y with the highest coefficient $a_n = 1$. You find all the integer solutions for y. The rational solutions for x are $y / a_n$, and you pick those that are integers.

Comment: $a_0 = -x\sum_{i=1}^n a_ix^{i-1}$. If $x$ is an integer root, $x$ divides $a_0$.